# JComboBox automatically selects first item in list

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to configure JComboBox not to select FIRST element when created?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762818/how-to-configure-jcombobox-not-to-select-first-element-when-created-java)

I have a JComboBox with a few selectable items in it. My problem is when the user click on the JComboBox, the list shows up as expected, but when he decide not to select any item and just clicks anywhere else on the frame, the JComboBox selects automatically the first item in the list. How do I avoid that, to not select the first item instead, to select the last one that was selected? I suppose that I need to override an JComboBox listener or something !?

Comment: I'm not sure why you need my code sample, this is a default JComboBox behavior and I'm not asking you to write code for me, just to point me in some direction.

I know I saw something like a listener on a JComboBox that has OnEdit and OnCancellation or something like that !?

Comment: @AlenBer I never see that, really

Comment: Maybe you could save the currently selected index before the combo box opens up, and then re-set the selected index if the user doesn't make a selection.

Comment: What you describe `is not` the default behaviour. The default behavour is that last selected item is retained when you click somewhere else in the frame. If you don't want to post your SSCCE then we can't help you.

Answer (score -1):

The best way is to provide your own ComboBoxModel which handle your case. Unfortunately, it is not easy to make this happen. Mainly in Read-Only CB it can be really tricky to identify user gesture correctly.

Comment: -1, attempting to manipulate the model is not the solution.