# How to load an enum populated ComboBox with no value selected

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, combobox, enums

On Netbeans, I have a jDialog with a jComboBox populated from values coming from a Java Enumeration. I need the default value of the Combo Box to be blank at start (or null or whatever), this way forcing the user to choose for a valid option. I have "selectedIndex" set to -1 but still the default value is my first enumeration value. So how can I have my Combo Box load with no value selected?

Thank you very much for your help.

Cheers.

Comment: Using `setSelectedIndex(-1)` works for me. Post your [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove and re-add the ItemListener as suggested in [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2766260/1196618).